# SELECT ROW_NUMBER() with Filters if Parameter populated?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL Server 2008 query.  I would like to augment it so that when the @Filter parameter is populated then pass that value to each field (across columns).  Without the filter the query works perfectly.  I am not sure if the filters should go where I have them. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pd_Get_Team2]
@OutTotalRecCount INT OUTPUT, 
@CurrentPage INT, 
@PageSize INT, 
@Token as nvarchar(50),
@UserID as nvarchar(50),
@SortDirection INT,
@SortField nvarchar(50),
@Filter nvarchar(50)

AS     
SELECT * FROM          
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 1 AND @SortField = 1 THEN pd_Role.UserID END ASC, 
CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 2 AND @SortField = 1 THEN pd_Role.UserID END DESC
) AS Row, 
pd_Role.id,      
pd_Role.Edit_Rights, 
pd_Role.UserID, 
pd_Role.Is_Approved, 
pd_Role.Login_Date, 
pd_Role.Team  

FROM pd_Role INNER JOIN  
pd_Token ON pd_Role.Token = pd_Token.Token 
WHERE 
(pd_Token.Token = @Token) AND (pd_Token.UserID = @UserID) 

 --how do I structure a filter on these fields if the filter is populated?
 --CASE WHEN LEN(@Filter)> 1  
 --AND pd_Role.Edit_Rights LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' OR 
 --AND pd_Role.UserID LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' OR 
 --AND pd_Role.Team LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' 
 --
  ) 
  AS TeamWithRowNumbers 
  WHERE  Row >= (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND Row <= @CurrentPage*@PageSize     

  SELECT @OutTotalRecCount = COUNT(*) FROM pd_Role 
  WHERE (pd_Role.Token = @Token)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if @Filter is never NULL (but might be blank):

```
WHERE 
(pd_Token.Token = @Token) AND (pd_Token.UserID = @UserID) 

AND (
    pd_Role.Edit_Rights LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' -- '%' + '' + '%' = Matches all
    OR pd_Role.UserID LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%'
    OR pd_Role.Team LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' 
)
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if pd_Role.Edit_Rights, pd_Role.UserID, pd_Role.Team can be NULL

Comment: They are never null. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AND ((@Filter IS NULL) OR
  (pd_Role.Edit_Rights LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' OR 
   AND pd_Role.UserID LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%' OR 
   AND pd_Role.Team LIKE '%' + @Filter + '%')
)
```

Be sure that `@Filter` is null when not supplied, or use `@Filter = ''` - I like the first approach.

Comment: If @Filter is '' will this bypass the filters? so only the where clause (WHERE 
(pd_Token.Token = @Token) AND (pd_Token.UserID = @UserID) filters the content?

Comment: If @Filter is '' you will have to change AND ((@Filter IS NULL) OR
 to AND ((@Filter = '') OR

Comment: It's just that I prefer to work with NULL parameters when they actually don't have a value.